# NSTokenField crashes when editing tokens

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstokenfield

I'm using `NSTokenField` and a corresponding `NSTokenFieldDelegate` to treat all text that is surrounded by dash characters `-` as rounded tokens and all other text as plain text.

The rounded tokens are displayed without the surrounding dashes and upon double-clicking on one of the tokens, the token switches in plain-text mode and shows the dashes.

In my `NSTokenFieldDelegate` implementation of

[`tokenField(NSTokenField, shouldAdd: [Any], at: Int) -> [Any]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstokenfielddelegate/1524376-tokenfield)

I'm inspecting the given tokens and create rounded tokens if necessary.

In certain situations, e.g., when committing the text change after editing by pressing the return key, the application crashes (tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.6). The demo project reports an index out of range exception with a stack trace I'm posting below for reference.

To reproduce the crash, follow these simple steps

1. Run the demo application
2. Enter "-Dash1-. -Dash2-" into the token field
3. Press return, the text changes to "`Dash1`. `Dash2`"
4. Double-click `Dash1` which then turns into "-Dash1-" and is selected
5. Press return

You can find the demo project at https://github.com/fheidenreich/token-test and I'm referencing the relevant code here:

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tokenField: NSTokenField!
}

class Token: Codable {
    let text: String
    let isRounded: Bool

    init(text: String, isRounded: Bool) {
        self.text = text
        self.isRounded = isRounded
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTokenFieldDelegate {

    func tokenField(_ tokenField: NSTokenField, displayStringForRepresentedObject representedObject: Any) -> String? {
        if let token = representedObject as? Token {
            if token.isRounded {
                return token.text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-")).capitalized(with: .current)
            } else {
                return token.text
            }
        }
        return representedObject as? String
    }

    func tokenField(_ tokenField: NSTokenField, styleForRepresentedObject representedObject: Any) -> NSTokenField.TokenStyle {
        if let token = representedObject as? Token {
            return token.isRounded ? .rounded : .none
        } else {
            return .none
        }
    }

    func tokenField(_ tokenField: NSTokenField, representedObjectForEditing editingString: String) -> Any? {
        var isRounded = editingString.hasPrefix("-") && editingString.hasSuffix("-") && editingString.count > 1
        if isRounded {
            // We treat it only as rounded token if we find no dashes inside the editing string
            let startIndex = editingString.index(after: editingString.startIndex)
            let endIndex = editingString.index(before: editingString.endIndex)
            let searchRange = startIndex..<endIndex
            let range = editingString.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-"), options: [], range: searchRange)
            isRounded = range == nil
        }
        return Token(text: editingString, isRounded: isRounded)
    }

    func tokenField(_ tokenField: NSTokenField, editingStringForRepresentedObject representedObject: Any) -> String? {
        if let token = representedObject as? Token {
            return token.text
        }
        return representedObject as? String
    }

    func tokenField(_ tokenField: NSTokenField, shouldAdd tokens: [Any], at index: Int) -> [Any] {
        if let tokens = tokens as? [Token] {
            var added = [Any]()

            for token in tokens {
                if token.isRounded {
                    added.append(token)
                    continue
                }

                let newTokens = createTokens(token.text)
                added.append(contentsOf: newTokens)
            }

            return added
        }
        return tokens
    }

    func createTokens(_ text: String) -> [Token] {
        guard let exp = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "-(.+?)-", options: []) else {
            return []
        }

        var tokens = [Token]()
        var previousEndLocation = 0
        let matches = exp.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))
        for match in matches {
            let range0 = match.range(at: 0) // Range that denotes the part before the match
            let range1 = match.range(at: 1) // Range that denotes the match

            if previousEndLocation < range0.location {
                let rangePrefix = NSRange(location: previousEndLocation, length: range0.location - previousEndLocation)
                // We found some text that prefixes the matches
                if rangePrefix.length > 0 {
                    if let swiftRange = Range(rangePrefix, in: text) {
                        let name = String(text[swiftRange])
                        tokens.append(Token(text: name, isRounded: false))
                    }
                }
            }

            if let swiftRange = Range(range1, in: text) {
                let name = "-" + text[swiftRange] + "-"
                tokens.append(Token(text: name, isRounded: true))
            }

            previousEndLocation = range0.location + range0.length
        }

        // We found some text that postfixes the matches
        if previousEndLocation < text.count {
            let range = NSRange(location: previousEndLocation, length: text.count - previousEndLocation)
            if let swiftRange = Range(range, in: text) {
                let name = String(text[swiftRange])
                tokens.append(Token(text: name, isRounded: false))
            }
        }

        return tokens
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why the application is crashing and possibly give hints in fixing or circumventing the issue?

```
2019-11-23 22:05:54.155614+0100 TokenTest[52583:3146671] !!! _NSGlyphTreeGlyphAtIndex missing glyphs
2019-11-23 22:05:54.160776+0100 TokenTest[52583:3146671] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2019-11-23 22:05:54.160940+0100 TokenTest[52583:3146671] [General] *** -[NSBigMutableString _getBlockStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:stopAtLineSeparators:]: Range {0, 5} out of bounds; string length 0
2019-11-23 22:05:54.200975+0100 TokenTest[52583:3146671] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff398e5bc9 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff640893c6 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff398e59fb +[NSException raise:format:] + 193
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff3bb23da2 -[NSString _getBlockStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:stopAtLineSeparators:] + 214
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff3bb23cc5 -[NSString getParagraphStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:] + 31
    5   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff60551488 _NSFastFillAllLayoutHolesForGlyphRange + 1425
    6   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff6053e260 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _firstPassGlyphRangeForBoundingRect:inTextContainer:okToFillHoles:] + 285
    7   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff6053d26c -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _glyphRangeForBoundingRect:inTextContainer:fast:okToFillHoles:] + 851
    8   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff6053cf12 -[NSLayoutManager glyphRangeForBoundingRect:inTextContainer:] + 67
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff36e7fdd8 -[NSTextView setNeedsDisplayInRect:avoidAdditionalLayout:] + 1205
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff36e7f91b -[NSTextView setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 41
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff36e5d109 -[NSView setNeedsDisplay:] + 79
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff370f26df -[NSTextView(NSSharing) setSelectedTextAttributes:] + 323
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff370f1daa _NSEditTextCellWithOptions + 1313
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff370f179f -[NSTextFieldCell _selectOrEdit:inView:target:editor:event:start:end:] + 357
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff3721123e -[NSTokenFieldCell _selectOrEdit:inView:target:editor:event:start:end:] + 147
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff370f1634 -[NSCell selectWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:start:length:] + 46
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff370f15fe __26-[NSTextField selectText:]_block_invoke + 94
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff36e47849 +[NSAppearance _performWithCurrentAppearance:usingBlock:] + 84
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff370f129a -[NSTextField selectText:] + 231
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff37105719 -[NSTextField textDidEndEditing:] + 1062
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff398920ea __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39892064 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39891fce _CFXRegistrationPost + 404
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3989a3fd ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 87
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3980340c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1834
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff398026b7 _CFXNotificationPost + 840
    27  Foundation                          0x00007fff3baa6a7b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff37215efb -[NSTextView(NSPrivate) _giveUpFirstResponder:] + 415
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff376b2aee -[NSTokenTextView insertNewline:] + 354
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fff37142ca6 -[NSTextView doCommandBySelector:] + 194
    31  AppKit                              0x00007fff37142bba -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) doCommandBySelector:completionHandler:] + 228
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff37137e1a -[NSKeyBindingManager(NSKeyBindingManager_MultiClients) interpretEventAsCommand:forClient:] + 2972
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff37803fdf __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_5 + 341
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff37803e75 __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3.784 + 74
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff3713ef23 -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 87
    36  AppKit                              0x00007fff37803dfb __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.781 + 237
    37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae7efb __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_5 + 70
    38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae6db9 ___ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec_block_invoke + 110
    39  AppKit                              0x00007fff377fe70e __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.265 + 575
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff37139512 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 74
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff3713949a -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 87
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff37138c92 -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:] + 1749
    43  AppKit                              0x00007fff37138545 _NSTSMEventHandler + 306
    44  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38a7d22e _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1422
    45  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38a7c5df _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 371
    46  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38a7c465 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 45
    47  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae3f8f SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 383
    48  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae43fa __SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 387
    49  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae4268 __SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 221
    50  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae3fde SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 462
    51  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae3de3 SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 225
    52  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae3aa4 SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler + 280
    53  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae384e __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 283
    54  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae36ad __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 355
    55  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae34cb TSMKeyEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 598
    56  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae325a __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_4 + 250
    57  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae3089 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_3 + 257
    58  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae2dce __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 282
    59  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae2b32 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 274
    60  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff38ae2127 TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler + 3398
    61  AppKit                              0x00007fff37803cd9 __84-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3.779 + 110
    62  AppKit                              0x00007fff378032d6 __204-[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:]_block_invoke.734 + 115
    63  AppKit                              0x00007fff378031c7 -[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent_orSubstitution:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionCondition:doubleSpaceSubstitutionWork:dispatchTSMWork:continuation:] + 245
    64  AppKit                              0x00007fff37803892 -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:allowingSyntheticEvent:completionHandler:] + 1286
    65  AppKit                              0x00007fff37803086 -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:allowingSyntheticEvent:] + 107
    66  AppKit                              0x00007fff37137004 -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:] + 209
    67  AppKit                              0x00007fff37136e2d -[NSTextView keyDown:] + 726
    68  AppKit                              0x00007fff36f84367 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6840
    69  AppKit                              0x00007fff36f82667 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 478
    70  AppKit                              0x00007fff36e22889 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 2953
    71  AppKit                              0x00007fff36e105c0 -[NSApplication run] + 755
    72  AppKit                              0x00007fff36dffac8 NSApplicationMain + 777
    73  TokenTest                           0x0000000100008cad main + 13
    74  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6584f3d5 start + 1
)
```

Comment: I cannot crash it on macOS 10.15.1 and Xcode 11.2.1, hope this helps.

Comment: @Vadim I've tried with macOS 10.15.1 and Xcode 11.2.1 in a virtual machine and still can reproduce the crash. Have you followed the steps above?

Comment: Ouch, I just started screen-recording a video and noticed that I click the selection by mouse to see a cursor just before hitting Return. False alarm, sorry! It really crashes when you reproduce it step-by-step.

Comment: Post your code in the question please.

Comment: @Willeke I've added the relevant code, the full Xcode project is available via the GitHub link.

Comment: Have you found a solution? In my project, I'm getting the same crash with the same out of bounds exception after typing and pressing Return. One thing I noticed is, that when I use comma (the default tokenizing character) instead of Return, it doesn't crash. It still throws an exception, but is ignoring it.  `<NSTokenFieldCell: 0x600003d1cd20>: Exception(*** -[NSBigMutableString substringWithRange:]: Range {0, 9} out of bounds; string length 1) raised while processing typed text. Ignoring...`

Comment: I haven't found a solution or workaround yet. I've noticed that it also crashes right away when I handle `controlTextDidChange` in my `NSTokenFieldDelegate` and I suspect that it's related to layout — as soon as layouting is involved it crashes.

Comment: I can confirm your observation when using the comma a tokenizing character: it requires a change of the selection and this works even when using Return. If you change the selection to be past `-Dash1-` in my example above, pressing Return also works.